# How to avoid resized images being blurred in Coldfusion?

Tags: image, coldfusion, resize, cfimage

I'm resizing and saving some images using `Coldfusion8`. However, all images, no matter what size are blurred and I don't know how to turn it off.

This is what I'm doing:

```
<cfimage action="read" source="#variables.basePath#" name="base">
<cfscript>
    variables.height = 127;
    variables.width = "";
    ImageScaleToFit(base, variables.width, variables.height);
    variables.offset = ImageGetWidth( base ) - 100;
    if ( variables.offset GT 0 )
    {
        imageCrop( base, variables.offset/2, 0, 100, 127 );
    }
    variables.filekey = "s_" & img_paths.bilddateiname;
    variables.filename = variables.tempDirectory & variables.keyName;
    imageWrite( base, variables.filename, ".99" );
 </cfscript>
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? The images are blurred no matter if I convert to 800x1110px or the above 100x127. The base picture is sharp, so it must be something I'm doing when resizing.

Thanks for inputs!

**EDIT:** 
original image:

[image]

resized image:

[image]

Comment: I notice that you're already using `.99` for quality, how's the file size compare to the original?

Comment: the file size is about the same. but see the difference (give me a few secs to upload)

Comment: Did you blow up the 100x127 image back to the original resolution somehow? See my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using CF9.0.2

Using your source jpeg, your code, and hardcode the output to be `y.jpg`:

[image: 8KB]

What's wrong?  Isn't this what you expect?

Comment: your's looks sharp. Mine is all blurry. I'm starting with a large image (called `base`) and then I'm resizing... could it be that I'm resizing the "resized image"?

Comment: could be? I don't know, but I'm just using the code you posted.

Comment: but ya, if possible, always resize from original and only resize it once for best quality.

Comment: `ImageScaleToFit` already resized your image, so do not resize again.

Comment: so, if I need an XL,L,M and S version of the image, start XL and work myself down?

Comment: no, for best quality, always resize from the original jpeg. So... `imageRead()` original, ImageScaleToFit, write. Then read again (or Duplicate() the `base` before resize might work, I'm not sure)

Comment: ok. Works halfway in my temp directory. Any idea why uploading from temp to Amazon S3 seems to be "blurring" images?